Changing color of code using lstlisting
I use lstlisting to show my code in the appendix of my rapport. I have problems with changing the color of the functions and types of data types. I hope to get the following result.

But I get the following output.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1, 0.65, 0}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codegreen},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
  
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Comparator:
    """Represents a comparator containing two channels i and j."""
    i: int
    j: int


def make_comparator(i: int, j: int) -> Comparator:
    """Creates a new instance of comparator between channels i and j.
       Precondition: i and j >= 0 and i != j
       >>>make_comparator(0, 1)
       Comparator(i=0, j=1)
    """
    return Comparator(i,j)


def min_channel(c: Comparator) -> int:
    """Returns the channel with lowest value.
       >>>min_channel(make_comparator(0, 1))
       0
       >>>min_channel(make_comparator(3, 2))
       2
    """
    if c.i < c.j:
        return c.i
    else:
        return c.j


def max_channel(c: Comparator) -> int:
    """Returns the channel with highest value.
       >>>max_channel(make_comparator(0, 1))
       1
       >>>min_channel(make_comparator(3, 2))
       3
    """
    if c.j > c.i:
        return c.j
    else:
        return c.i

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


Make your example compilable. This will enable others to respond more quickly.

@projetmbc Thanks you. I forgot that I used code from another file:) This should run

Using keywordstyle=[2]⟨style⟩ it is possible to apply a ⟨style⟩ to the built-in keywords already defined for Python, such as int.
The custom functions defined in the code can be emphasized by defining an appropriate style using  emphstyle.
Since the word Comparator appears in different contexts, the class name was colored by defining special delimiters using escapeinside={<opening delim>}{<closing delim>} so that code between them could be evaluated.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1, 0.65, 0}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    escapeinside={|}{|}, %<<<<<<<
    columns=flexible,
    % keyword highlighting
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},% core keywords <<<<<
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{codepurple}}, % built-ins <<<<
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{red},       
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codegreen},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    emph=[1]%
    {%  functions <<<<<<<
    make_comparator,
    min_channel,
    max_channel,
    },
    emphstyle=[1]{\color{blue}},% <<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    
    @dataclass
    class |\textcolor{blue}{Comparator:}|                                            
    """Represents a comparator containing two channels i and j."""
    i: int
    j: int
    
    
    def make_comparator (i: int, j: int) -> Comparator:
    """Creates a new instance of comparator between channels i and j.
    Precondition: i and j >= 0 and i != j
    >>>make_comparator(0, 1)
    Comparator(i=0, j=1)
    """
    return Comparator(i,j)
    
    
    def min_channel(c: Comparator) -> int:
    """Returns the channel with lowest value.
    >>>min_channel(make_comparator(0, 1))
    0
    >>>min_channel(make_comparator(3, 2))
    2
    """
    if c.i < c.j:
    return c.i
    else:
    return c.j
    
    
    def max_channel(c: Comparator) -> int:
    """Returns the channel with highest value.
    >>>max_channel(make_comparator(0, 1))
    1
    >>>min_channel(make_comparator(3, 2))
    3
    """
    if c.j > c.i:
    return c.j
    else:
    return c.i

\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}


Thank you so much for the help!
